# GPG error: The following signatures were invalid

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ставил Numix, появились проблемы при подключения его репозитория, однако проблема не только с ним. При обновлении пакетов некоторые репозитории не работают.
Ошибка:

```
W: Ошибка GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu raring Release: Следующие подписи неверны: C5ACDE79014125D8F25B843ABDCB16CCBE796FF2
E: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu raring Release» не подписан.
```

Пытался следать по этому гайду:

> 1. Перейдите на сервер открытых ключей OpenPGP . Там вы можете ввести свой ключ в Search Stringполе, оставив все остальное как есть, затем
>    нажать «Поиск!».   При поиске ключа всегда готовьтесь 0xк нему ! Это
>    означает, что, например, вы должны искать 0x6AF0E1940624A220 вместо
>    6AF0E1940624A220.
> 2. Нажмите на ссылку, представленную в pub разделе. Это должно привести вас к странице, содержащей ключ. Заголовок страницы должен
>    быть похож наPublic Key Server -- Get "0x6AF0E1940624A220"
> 3. Скопируйте все из-под заголовка (начиная с -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----) и сохраните его в файле (например key1).
> 4. Получив файл, выполните следующую команду
>
>    sudo apt-key add key1
>
> Вы получите ответ «ОК».

После решения по гайду был получен ответ "ОК", но ошибка не исчезла.

Comment: `raring`? Ты используешь бубен семилетней давности? Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообще ошибка вызвана тем, что истёк срок действия ключа, которым подписан файл Release (т.е., другими словами, «подпись репозитория»):

> ```
> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: C5ACDE79014125D8F25B843ABDCB16CCBE796FF2
> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu raring Release' is not signed.
> ```

версия 13.04 (кодовое имя `raring`) [вышла в 2013 году (а поддержка её закончилась в 2014)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_Ubuntu). вряд ли вы используете эту версия дистрибутива.

выберите свою версию дистрибутива из тех, для которых есть пакеты в [нужном вам репозитории](http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu/dists/). впрочем, репозиторий давно не поддерживается (судя по опубликованным там версиям — самая «свежая» для `yaketty`), и если версия вашего дистрибутива новее чем 16.10 (кодовое имя `yaketty`), то если пакеты даже и установятся, совсем не факт, что программы из них заработают (понятно, что в sources.list надо будет указать `xenial` — это lts-версия).

---

если же у вас **на самом деле** ubuntu 13.04, то, ввиду того, что подпись репозитория для **этой** версии уже «протухла», можете [отключить проверку подписи](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46562801/4827341), добавив `[trusted=yes]` в его описание:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu raring main
```

Answer (score 0):

Мои пять копеек.
Команда автоматически найдет и добавит нужные ключи безопасности подключенных репозиториев, если Вы им полностью доверяете
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com `sudo apt-get update 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9A-Z]\{16\}$' | xargs`
[PPA for the Numix Project Ltd](https://launchpad.net/%7Enumix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

[image: PPA for the Numix Project Ltd]

Comment: это, конечно, очень интересно, но к данному вопросу отношения не имеет: ключ как раз имеется, вот только в данном случае — просроченный.

Comment: Если у Вас действительно Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) - в первую очередь надо поменять sources.list. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/  Т.е. deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse и т.д.

Comment: Если Вам нужна подборка программ для математиков, научных работников и студентов от AIMS поставьте второй системой AIMS Desktop (https://desktop.aims.ac.za) installation guide там подробнейший https://desktop.aims.ac.za/getting-started/  The AIMS Desktop team is proud to announce AIMS Desktop 2020.1. This release is based on Debian 10, and through some careful planning, we’re releasing it on the same day as the official Debian 10 release on Saturday, 5 July 2020.